# Python - compare multiple columns, search list of keywords in column and compare with another, in two dataframes to generate a third resultset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, tuples

I have two very different dataframes.

df1 looks like this:

| Region | Entity | Desk | Function | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | AAA | Top class, Desk1, Mike's team | Writing, advising | Unique_1 |
| US | AAA | team beta, Blue rats, Tom | task_a, task_d | Unique_2 |
| EMEA | ZZZ | Delta one | Forecasts, month-end, Sales | Unique_3 |
| JPN | XYZ | Admin | task1, task_b, task_g | Unique_4 |

df2 looks like this:

| Region | Entity | Desk | Function | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMEA | ZZZ | Equity, delta one | Sales, sweet talking, schmoozing | A_01 |
| US | AAA | Desk 1, A team, Top class | Writing,calling,listening, advising | A_02 |
| US | AAA | Desk 2, Ninjas, 2nd team, Tom's team | Secret, private | A_03 |
| EMEA | DDD | Equity, Private Equity | task1, task2, task3, task4 | A_04 |
| JPN | XXX | Admin, Secretaries | task_a, task_b | A_05 |

df2 is a much larger recordset than df1.

Both Desk and Function in each of the dataframes were free-text fields and allowed the input of rubbish data.  I am trying to build a new recordset from these dataframes using the following criteria:
where -
df1['Region'] == df2['Region']
AND
df1['Entity'] == df2['Entity']
AND
any of the phrases within df1['Desk'] can be matched to any of the phrases within df2['Desk']
AND
any of the phrases within df1['Function'] can be matched to any of the phrases within df2['Function'].

I need the ultimate output to look something like this:

| df2.Id | df1.Key | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_02 | Unique_1 | Exact |
|  | Unique_2 | No match |
| A_01 | Unique_3 | Exact |
|  | Unique_4 | No match |

I am really struggling with this.  I have both dataframes but I cannot loop through df1 to match the columns as specified above in df2.  I've tried merging the dataframes, using np.where and brute force looping but nothing is working.  The tricky bit is matching the Desk and Function columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: They are Primary Keys in each dataframe.

Comment: but `A_01` (from `df2`) can not join with `Unique_4` (from `df1`) - they differ in Region/Entity

Comment: I am trying to match df1 and df2 on multiple columns.  Those columns are Region, Entity, Desk and Function.  Matching on Region and Entity is possible, but matching on Desk and Function is problematic because I have to perform a keyword search.  If any keywords from df1.Desk are found in df2.Desk and if any keywords from df1.Function are found in df2.Function then we have a match.  Where a match on all columns is found, I add a row to Table 3.  Table 3 just contains the Primary Keys from df1 and df2 along with narrative on whether a match was found based on the aforementioned columns.

Comment: And you are right, there are no matches in df2 for row Unique_4 in df1, as shown in table 3 (output) above.

Comment: I meant that `A_01` and `Unique_4` should NOT be compared at all

Comment: As table 3 shows, there is no match for Unique_04 in df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one option is to use a *cross* [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```
def cross_match(df1, df2, col):
    df = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
    
    colx, coly = [f"{col}_x", f"{col}_y"]
    df[[colx, coly]] = df[[colx, coly]].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()
                                                         .str.split("\s*,\s*"))
    
    df["MATCH"] = (pd.Series([any(w in sent for w in lst)
                             for lst, sent in zip(df[f"{col}_x"], df[f"{col}_y"])])
                   .map({True:"Exact"}))
    
    return df.query("MATCH == 'Exact'")

desk, func = cross_match(df1, df2, "Desk"), cross_match(df1, df2, "Function")

out = (
        pd.merge(desk, func,
                 left_on=["Region_x", "Entity_x", "ID"],
                 right_on=["Region_y", "Entity_y", "ID"],
                 suffixes=("", "_")).set_index("Key")
            .reindex(df1["Key"].unique())
            .fillna({"MATCH": "No match"})
            .reset_index()[["ID", "Key", "MATCH"]]
      )
```

*Disclaimer : This approach may get incredibly slow when huge datasets* (`df1`, `df2`)*.*

Output :

```
print(out)

     ID       Key     MATCH
0  A_02  Unique_1     Exact
1   NaN  Unique_2  No match
2  A_01  Unique_3     Exact
3   NaN  Unique_4  No match
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this.  Your solution provided a clever answer to a thorny problem.  One thing I noticed was unfortunately it will only work on one-to-one matches, else the index is messed up and it throws the following error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.  The real-life data is unfortunately much messier than the example provided, but your smart solution certainly worked where there were no multiple matches on the same index.

Comment: You're welcome, if you give another example where there is multiple matches, I'll see what can I do. Also, don't forget to update the expected output ;)